# FTP Uploaded file is corrupted

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to upload PDF file using FTP mode in ASP.NET , file upload is successful but the resulted file is currupted, please give me the solution.

```
public void UploadFTPTextFile(string ftpServer, string ftpFolder, string user, string passward, string NName, FileUpload FileUpload1)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    string fileName = NName;
    using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {
        fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStream.ReadToEnd());
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    //Create FTP Request.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer + ftpFolder + fileName);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passward);
    request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
    request.EnableSsl = false;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to upload pdf file using ftp mode in asp.net , file upload success full but it is currupt , please give me the solution , Thanks

Comment: Please improve format so we can understand your problem, and state the error that you get

Comment: Is the file definitely encoded as UTF-8? Try writing the file out to a new file on your file system first and compare the bytes between the two. Once they're identical, then try doing the upload.

Comment: Do not use a text file uploader to upload PDF.  PDF is a binary format while text is in the ASCII range.

Comment: Your PDF won't be using the utf-8 encoding, it'll be pure binary.

Comment: Thanks I have got the solution from other post of stackoverflow.com,

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is reading input file to bytes. You suppose, that it is in UTF8 encoding, but FTP does not interpret the text and no encoding is needed. You should just read bytes, because FTP server just saves bytes. Use [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
public void UploadFTPTextFile(string ftpServer, string ftpFolder, string user, string passward, string NName, FileUpload FileUpload1)
{
    string fileName = NName;
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    //Create FTP Request.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpServer + ftpFolder + fileName);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, passward);
    request.ContentLength = fileBytes.Length;
    request.UsePassive = true;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = fileBytes.Length;
    request.EnableSsl = false;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }
}
```

If you would like to use even more elegant solution (for huge files), use [Stream.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) and copy the opened file to requestStream without using fileBytes.